# How to get postgres sql timestamp in 'DD-Mon-YYYY' format?

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

My Datestyle:

```
=> show datestyle;
    DateStyle
   -----------
     ISO, YMD
```

Its showing format as:

```
=> select now()::DATE;
now
------------
 2013-10-17
```

But I want the output:

```
now
------------
 17-Oct-2013
```

This can be done using `TO_CHAR(timestamp,'MON-YY')` but its datatype changes to character string I want the datatype as timestamp only

Comment: Any solution at database end so far?

Answer (score 1):

Formatting of values should happen in the application or client and not in the database layer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you will be able to preserve the format without changing the date style. Or as @Michael-O has suggested, you can fetch and format at the business level

Answer (score 1):

My application is purely big data solution for large set of data so I want maximum utilization of database functionality than writing customize code at application level.

This can be done by using one hack:
As I said `TO_CHAR(timestamp,'MON-YY')` can be used to convert type.

We can simply convert `TO_CHAR(timestamp,'MON-YY')` value to date by using
`('01-' || TO_CHAR(timestamp,'MON-YY')):: DATE`